# Django current location bar

Tags: django, navigation

I would like to "current location bar" id Django. Something like on eBay under the "Women clothing" (eBay>Fashion>Women's Clothing), but I don't really know how to do it.

I was wondering if I should use request.get_full_path() or something like that, but it seems very dirty to me.

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "breadcrumbs" and you can find a nice snippet [here](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1026/)

As said there:

```
The URL 
    /users/foo/config/
will get to these breadcrumbs:
    Users>>foo>>Config
```

which is basically the correct way to understand this snippet!
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you're wanting the full breadcrumb trail?

Usually you just use django's url template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url and reverse each known url for where you are on the site.